# Do people still use ACT-R?

Tags: cognitive-neuroscience, computational-modeling, neural-network, cognitive, act-r

A lot of computational cognitive scientists seem to be working on Neural nets (mostly vision scientists), Reinforcement learning (mostly decision making people) and Bayesian Inferences. I could hardly find anyone working on ACT-R. Is it still relevant?

Comment: [D'Angiulli, A., & Devenyi, P. (2019). Retooling computational techniques for EEG-based neurocognitive modeling of children’s data, validity and prospects for learning and education. *Frontiers in Computational Neuroscience, 13*, 4.](https://doi.org/10.3389/fncom.2019.00004) uses ACT-R so I would say it is still relevant.

Comment: To be honest I am at a loss with your question. The comment before and https://doi.org/10.3390/app11093967 talks of ACT-R in Human-Computer Interaction research. What makes you question if it is still relevant?

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in the comments, ACT-R is still actively being used in recent research publications. A simple example of that can be found by a quick Google Scholar search. But likely you are more interested in *how much* it is still being used.

Personally, although I never used ACT-R myself, I read papers using it in the field of Human-Computer Interaction as part of my research on multitasking. I remember Altmann as a frequently cited author using ACT-R as part of their methodologies. My memory seems to serve me right, since a quick search shows up [his publication list on the ACT-R website](http://act-r.psy.cmu.edu/?post_type=authors&p=10327), but granted only with publications up to 2012.

However, [on the same website you can **browse all publications related to ACT-R**](http://act-r.psy.cmu.edu/publication/), which in and of itself should answer your question. 7 publications were listed for 2020, and so far 5 are listed for 2021.